# alert in jquery onChange event

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, alert, onchange

My code is below. What I want is, when the drop down value is equal to '1' I want to alert.But it is not working. Here is my code.

```
<div>
    <select id="number">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>

</div> 
$('#number').change(function()
   {
        if($('#number').val()=='1'){
        alert('f');
   });

}
```

Here the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tfx0s33e/)

Comment: `$('#number').change(function () {
    if ($('#number').val() == '1') {
        alert('f');
    }
})` typos - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mkgtvo3v/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed the if loop. Use:

```
$('#number').change(function()
                {
                    if($('#number').val()=='1'){
                     alert('f');
                    }});
                  //^ braces missing
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suzu5oxg/)**

Answer (score 1):

There is brackets problem,below answer is working :-

```
$('#number').change(function()
{
    if($('#number').val()=='1'){
    alert('f');
    }    //close if brackets here
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pcLc2j8v/)

Answer (score 1):

You're mis-ordering closing brackets:

```
$('#number').change(function(){
   if($('#number').val()=='1'){
      alert('f');
   } // not });    
}); // not }
```

---

So, I suggest you to indent your code which help you a lot while debugging.